# How to transfer ownership of file create with service account using Drive API v3

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using the `googleapis` package in `npmjs` to create a spreadsheet as follows:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis")
const sheets = google.sheets("v4")
const drive = google.drive("v3")


async function run() {
    // ....
    // auth obtained here
    // ....

    var resp = await sheets.spreadsheets.create({
        auth,
        resource: {
            properties: {
                title:"SSTEST2",
            }
        }
    })
    var folder = "1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" // actual folder id omitted
    var ssid = resp.data.spreadsheetId
    resp = await drive.files.update({
        auth,
        addParents:[folder],
        removeParents:"root",
        fileId:ssid
    })
}
```

I'm using a service account I created, so as a result when the process is complete, the spreadsheet is owned by googlesheetsuser@some-random-words.iam.gserviceaccount.com.  This doesn't seem to prevent me from editing the document, however if I delete it, presumably it is still sitting off in limbo somewhere (if I try to access it before moving it to my folder I get a page telling me to request access, which doesn't make any sense because a service account address isn't a real e-mail and so there's no way for this to succeed!) so I'm not sure if it's even going into a trash can for the service account or if it will sit around on Google's servers forever.  Not actually owning the document causes issues so I need to get ownership.

On the other hand, I haven't found any documentation that explains exactly what I need to do to transfer ownership to myself.  Google's API seem to leave out a lot of information about exactly what to pass; leaving out important info in the sample source with comments like "TODO: Add desired properties to the request body" is beyond unhelpful!  I have found a few examples in other languages using other mechanisms I don't recognize which purport to do at least something close to this, but I haven't been able to glean any useful information about how to do it in my particular setup.  I have also found a couple of answers which seem to imply that doing this is impossible as you can't change ownership between domains, in which case I just have no words because obviously leaving it owned by my service account creates issues and leaving it owned by the service account indefinitely just isn't an option so some solution is needed.

How can I wind up with my file (Google Spreadsheet) owned by myself at the end of this process?

Update: Per the suggested by @Kessy, I tried to use this code:

```
const resp = await drive.permissions.update({
    auth,
    fileId: <fileId>,
    permissionId: <id found using list call>,
    transferOwnership: true,
    requestBody: {
        role: "owner",
        emailAddress: <my email address>,
        type: "user",
    }
})
```

I get this error:

```
Error: The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.
```

I don't know which field it thinks isn't writeable.  I tried omitting "type" and get the same error.  I tried omitting "role" and it complains that this field is required: `Error: The permission role field is required.` If I omit "emailAddress" then I don't get the error, but this defeats who whole purpose of the call, which is to transfer ownership *to that e-mail address*!

Comment: Where is the file stored, in your drive or a shared drive? If you store it on your drive, you can use the parameter `transferOwnership` from [Permissions: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update)

Comment: @Kessy Thanks!  I have been able to move it to a folder in my drive.  I wlll try that as soon as I get a chance here.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve it? If so, please create an accepted answer so more people can benefit from it, if not, update the question or provide more information.

Comment: @Kessy Sorry, it's still on my list to do, I just haven't gotten to it yet.  I'll update as soon as I have tried it.

Comment: @Kessy No, I'm not able to get it to work.  I had to call `list` to even get all the necessary parameters (permissionId was a random looking number string) but I get the error `The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable` despite that I am passing "role", "emailAddress", and "type" (although I also tried omitting the last with no difference in the error).

Comment: As another option, have you considered using impersonation when creating the file so  you are already the owner of the file?.

Comment: @Kessy Do you mean use OAuth2 credentials instead of a service account?

Comment: Hi, no it is not using OAuth2 credentials. It is using the service account to act as your account to create the file. This is explained on the [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)